# php outputs sourcecode instead of running nginx

Tags: php

I have this showing up on my site.  the lang function is showing on the web, but not runned as it should run on the site. The server is running nginx

**Q: Why is it doing that, and how can it be prevented?**

[image]

content of file:

```
    <?

function lang($line) {

    $ci = & get_instance();
    $languageVariable = explode(" ", $line);
    $outcome = '';
        foreach($languageVariable as $langLine) {
        $outcome .= $ci->lang->line($langLine);

        }
        return $outcome;


}

function langW($string, $var1 = FALSE, $var2 = FALSE, $var3 = FALSE)
{
    return sprintf(lang($string), ($var1 ? $var1 : ''), ($var2 ? $var2 : ''));
}



function langV($line, $var)
{
    $ci = & get_instance();
    return sprintf($ci->lang->line($line), $var);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have Apache running or other web server

Comment: If there is an error, please paste it as text. When you do, also paste it in Google. You're likely not the first one who's got it.

Comment: hmm. how can i get it to work with nginx?

Comment: <?  make this to  <?php , it will definately work :)

Comment: I assume you have short tags enabled?

Comment: As @n01ze said you need your tags to start with <?php, not <?. Also make sure you're running an APACHE server.. for local tests and such, use XAMPP or WAMP

Comment: i see. thanks.

How can i enable these short tags?

Comment: Just for future reference those are  **not source code** those are **error messages**

Comment: @maria goto `php.ini` file  and make sure you have `short_open_tag = On`

Comment: sorry not related to this question , dude your name @HawasKaPujaari :P

Comment: @n01ze Sshhh! Angrezo ko pata chal jayega ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in php.ini, then restart your nginx server

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

If you can't edit php.ini, then you can either replace all your `<?` to `<?php` (not the best..) or add the following to the `.htaccess` file in your document root:

```
php_value short_open_tag 1
```

Remember that your hosting could have disabled this option, so it's not 100% guaranteed that the .htaccess way works.

Comment: Just to note (although, this pretty much depends on the person), it's not fully impracticle to use `<?php`, as you can still use `<?`, but it will be short for `<?php echo`. Again, this is a matter of personal preference, but it does speed things up, especilly if you're doing Object Oriented PHP

Comment: `<?` is not a shorthand for `<?php echo`; did you mean `<?=`?

Comment: I'll correct it.. ASP made me forget of the little things PHP.